# How can I keep SSH connection going on WIFI if Ethernet goes out?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, ssh, ethernet, connection

I'd like to keep my SSH connection alive over WIFI even if the Ethernet goes out. There is an Ethernet and WIFI connection, however if the Ethernet is unplugged I still lose my SSH access.  I'm doing this on a Raspberry Pi, but the question could apply to anything running linux.

Is there a way to keep the SSH connection going if I lose one of the two internet connections?

Whenever the Ethernet is unplugged, the SSH host get's broken even though the board still has internet.  This also happens with tunnels using ngrok or cloudflared (argo).

Comment: Crossdupe https://serverfault.com/questions/19634/how-to-reconnect-to-a-disconnected-ssh-session . In addition to screen or tmux, which were designed back in serial-line days and handle disconnecting/reconnecting _any_ type of connection, mosh is optimized to handle disconnecting/reconnecting Internet-including-SSH.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to deal with this (but its not an answer to your question) is to use tmux or screen so you can resume your session.

In order to ensure your session does not break, you need to ensure the IP source and target remain available.  There are many ways to do this, although none are trivial.

The most generic one I can think of would be to ensure you connect via a VPN. If you use something like OpenVPN (especially if you use multiple connection options), your TCP connection will continue regardless as long as the VPN tunnel remains, and that your IP doesn't change. This is true even if your underlying connection or location changes - as long as your run devices remain in tact.

I posit you may also be able to solve the problem using channel bonding - is you bond the Ethernet and WiFi devices into a bond0 interface and use that rather then the underlying interface. It might be a bit tricky to handle the bonding balancing - but active backup mode should work.

You might also be able to get away with replacing the IP address of the WIFI connection with that normally assigned to the Ethernet connection, but detecting and doing this might be problematic.